# How do I update a Holt-Winters model in R?

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, predictive-models

I am currently using Holt-Winters model to predict time series data. When new data becomes available how do I update my model to account for the change in seasonality and trends?

Comment: Are you asking how this can be done (in a software-neutral sense), or are you asking for R code? Be aware that the latter is off topic here. Please edit to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are using `stats::HoltWinters()`, not `forecast::dshw()` or `forecast::ets()`. Please do tell us the specific function you are using, although it doesn't really make a difference here.

There is no updating method for either of all these functions, as there is for `lm` objects (`update.lm()`). The simplest way would just be to refit your model. If you use `forecast::ets()`, you could constrain the new model to use the same functional form as the old one by specifying the `model` parameter. If you really want to, you could probably take the results of the old model and feed them into the underlying calls to `optim` as starting value, which could conceivably speed up your new fitting.

Finally, this type of question is better asked at [StackOverflow in the R tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r).